# losing primary key and constraints while importing database from sql server to azure sql server

Tags: sql-server, azure

Losing primary key and constraints while importing database from sql server to azure sql server : sql server version 11.0.2100.60

Comment: How do you process the import?

Comment: Did you try using `.bacpac` ?